# IIS: How to disable Data Execution Prevention in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2008, dep

I've been trying to disable DEP on my windows 2008 dev box and have not succeeded.

I've tried:
System Properties->Performance Options->Data Execution Prevention->Turn on DEP for essential Windows programs and services only

(still happens)

System Properties->Performance Options->Data Execution Prevention->Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select

in this case, i tried to choose both inetinfo.exe and w3wp.exe in the c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\ folder, and when selected, I receive this error:

"You can not set DEP attributes on 64-bit executables".

I'm sure that there is some memory leak somewhere - but that is a separate problem.   I'm happy to live with it for a while in my development environment (in fact that is where I need to let it go so I can see it)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thx,
Doug

Comment: What does (still happens) mean?  What are you observing?  What do you expect?

Comment: Running a system without DEP on is like driving without wearing a seatbelt...Why would you want to?

Comment: Probably better on server fault?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GUI does not show the 4 modes of DEP operation.

You need to do it at boot time:[Boot Parameters to Configure DEP and PAE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468629.aspx)

However, more info on [the error message](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738483(WS.10).aspx):

> System DEP configuration settings
>   apply only for 32-bit applications and
>   processes when running on 32-bit or
>   64-bit versions of Windows. On 64-bit 
>   versions of Windows, if
>   hardware-enforced DEP is available it
>   is always  applied to 64-bit processes
>   and kernel memory spaces and there are
>   no system  configuration settings to
>   disable it.

Comment: Downvoted. Solution should be explained here, not linked externally (link has since moved).

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to disable DEP at the command prompt:

```
BCDEDIT /set {current} nx AlwaysOff
```

Answer (score 4):

On Windows Vista and later, DEP and PAE are enabled at boot time and are configured by setting values for the nx and pae parameters using the BCDEdit /set command.

To disable DEP on Windows Server 2008 type the following on an elevated Command Line

```
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOff
```

Answer (score 1):

you would want to edit boot.ini and change a section contaning /noexecute=optin to just /execute

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to turn DEP off in one of your BIOS settings.

Comment: Hardware NX/xD bit only, Software DEP may still be enforced.