# Phony Access Exception on Push instruction in 32-bit windows code

Tags: access-violation

I have a complicated 32-bit multi-threaded program running on a 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1 system.

Running under the MSVC debugger, I sometimes stop with an access violation reported on an instruction inside winsock code, an instruction that has no obvious reason to be causing an exception. A typical example:

82 threads reported by the debugger. The one that is selected when the access violation
triggers a program break shows this...

Registers:

```
 EAX = 0DBC9918 EBX = 54007022
 ECX = 00374248 EDX = 00000000
 ESI = 00000000 EDI = 00370924
 EIP = 745616B4 ESP = 0DBC98C8
 EBP = 0DBC9934 EFL = 00010246
```

Disassembly:

```
745616B4 68 27 2F 58 74       push        74582F27h
745616B9 64 FF 35 00 00 00 00 push        dword ptr fs:[0]
745616C0 8B 44 24 10          mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+10h]
745616C4 89 6C 24 10          mov         dword ptr [esp+10h],ebp
```

Memory (address esp-4)

```
0DBC98C4  00370844  745636C2  74563808  0000003C  
0DBC98D4  75B83D70  00000002  00000001  00000000
```

The stack frontier data comes from a couple of pushes and a call that seem to have worked just fine:

```
745636B6 6A 3C                push        3Ch
745636B8 68 08 38 56 74       push        74563808h
745636BD E8 F2 DF FF FF       call        745616B4
745636C2 ...
```

It doesn't seem like the push at should be hitting a guard page exception, given its address and the successful pushes that preceded it. The other threads don't seem to be likely candidates for causing the exception, judging from the call-stack info. I don't know whether there's some mechanism I'm overlooking that could generate that access violation on that instruction, or whether the debugger is misleading me. Any light you can shed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That would be [DEP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209052/iis-how-to-disable-data-execution-prevention-in-windows-server-2008) for sure (data execution prevention).
Just had exactly same issue, similar code; spent a few hours on this stuff; keeping forgetting that UAC and DEP are two different things.